# vanilla JavaScript solution to check if number has no more than 6 digits and 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript

I need to return a validation check (boolean) if a number has no more than 6 number of digits and no more than 2 decimal places.

For example:

```
1 = valid
10 = valid
111111 = valid
111111.11 = valid
1111111.11 = INVALID
1.111 = INVALID
```

Looking through stack overflow I can only find answers where the input is automatically rounded (not what I want) or the decimal places have to be equal to exactly 2 decimal places (not at most 2).

Comment: You'll want to set up a regex for it. Unfortunately, I suck at those, so I'll leave it to you to figure it out, or someone will eventually post one for you :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously, you need

```
function valid(n) { 
  return no_more_than_six_digits(n) && no_more_than_two_decimal_places(n);
}
```

So how do we define these functions?

```
function no_more_than_six_digits        (n) { return n < 1e7; }
function no_more_than_two_decimal_places(n) { return Math.floor(n * 100) === n * 100; }
```

Answer (score 2):

This function should work

```
function t(x) {
    return x < 1000000 && Math.floor(x*100)/100 == x;
}
```

Example
http://jsfiddle.net/q6511o17/1/

But Check torazaburos answer for a more complete solution and explanation.

Comment: Using `parseInt` is a bit odd. It turns the argument into a string and then parses it into an integer. `Math.floor` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Good call, yes Math.floor is better.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, but works.

```
function validate(x) {
    return Math.floor(x) < 1000000 && 
    (x.toString().indexOf('.') == -1 ? 
    true : x.toString().split('.')[1].length < 3)
}
```